# Ошибка 500 при AJAX запросе

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

Возникает ошибка 500 (Internal Server Error) при отправке AJAX запроса, ошибка только при запросе на удаление из базы

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("DELETE FROM `notifications` WHERE `id` = $id")
            ->queryAll();
```

При SELECT * FROM и.т.д проблем никаких нет AJAX не выдает ошибок, да и сам запрос на удаление отрабатывает нормально и удаляет столбец в таблице, но AJAX возвращает ошибку 500
В чём может быть проблема? Благодарю!

Comment: Откройте вкладку "Сеть" в панели разработчика, и посмотрите из-за чего ошибка

Comment: + надо более подробно посмотреть ошибку, возможно в $id ничего нет

Answer (score 1):

Можно проще сделать

```
Notifications::deleteAll(['id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для выполнения не-select запросов через createCommand лучше использовать `->execute()`. Детали можно найти здесь: 
https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-dao/#non-select-queries

Answer (score 0):

Отменил AJAX и отправил этот запрос через форму из вьюшки в результате получил ошибку на уровне PDO 
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error это и была причина 500 (Internal Server Error) в консоли.

Я пока еще не очень понимаю с чем связана эта ошибка, но было явно понятно что дебагер ругается на:

```
->queryAll();
```

Старый запрос:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("DELETE FROM `notifications` WHERE `id` = $id")->queryAll();
```

Новый рабочий запрос:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("DELETE FROM `notifications` WHERE `id` = $id")->query();
```

Ну как, они оба работали, но второй не вызывает ошибку :)